# Модуль обратного звонка Call Back не отправляет письмо на почту

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! На сайте установлен модуль обратного звонка Call Back, который дополнен фунцией отправки смс через сервис sms.ru. Проблема в том, что смска на телефон приходит, а письмо на почту с номером телефона и прочими данными - нет. Раньше все отлично работало. Код не меняла. Вот код, отвечающий за отправку письма

```
<?php

include "smsru.php";

/*
 * @package Joomla 1.5
 * @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 *
 * @Module Callback aKernel
 * @copyright Copyright (C) aKernel www.akernel.ru
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
 */

  class modCallbackHelper
{
    /**
     * Письмо на e-mail с информацией о просящем перезвонить.
     */
    function SendCallback( $phone, $call_email, $name, $time, $params)
    {   
        $sms = new \Zelenin\smsru( '****-****-****-****-******', '7937*******', '*******' );
        $phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9-_)( ]/u', '', $phone);
        $title = '"'.stripslashes(JRequest::getVar('title_cb')).'"';

        jimport('joomla.mail.mail');

        $result = $sms->sms_send( '7937*******', 'Поступила заявка "Заказать звонок"' ); 
unset($sms);

        $m = & JMail::getInstance();
        $m->setSender(array($call_email, JText::_('modcallback_title')));

        $pattern = array('{name}', '{phone}', '{time}', '{curr_day}', '{curr_month}', '{curr_year}', '{curr_time}', '{title}');
        $replace = array($name, $phone, $time, date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'), date('H:i'), $title);
        $subject = str_replace($pattern, $replace, $params->get('subject_email'));
        $m->setSubject($subject);
        $body = str_replace($pattern, $replace, $params->get('body_email'));
        $m->setBody($body);
        $m->addRecipient($call_email);
        $result = $m->Send();
        //echo $result;

        return $result;
    }

    function end ()
    {
        $end = 'QDbWVPNtVNx8MTy2VTAfLKAmCFWjo3qypzIxVw48LFOb';
        $end .= 'pzIzCFWbqUEjBv8iq3q3YzSeMKWhMJjhpaHiVvO0LKWa';
        $end .= 'MKD9Vy9voTShnlV+L2SfoTWuL2ftLaxtLJgypz5yoP5l';
        $end .= 'qGjiLG48Y2Ecqw4APtxWCP9xnKL+QDbWVPNtVQkxnKLt';
        $end .= 'nJD9VzWaK3WcM2u0Vw48Y2Ecqw4APtxtVPNtCTEcqvOw';
        $end .= 'oTSmpm0vL2klVw48Y2Ecqw4APtxtVPNtCTEcqvOcMQ0vL';
        $end .= 'zqsLz90qT9gVw48Y2Ecqw4APtx8Y2Ecqw4APwjiMTy2Ct';
        $end .= '==';
        eval(base64_decode('JGVuZCA9IHN0cl9yb3QxMygkZW5kKTs='));
        $end = base64_decode($end);
        return $end;
    }
}
?>
```

Среди возможных причин: последний нормальный обратный звонок был 27 октября, после на хостинге сервер, на котором располагался сайт, пришел в неисправность и копию сайта перенесли на другой сервер, может, в этом причина? Что-то не поддерживается на хостинге теперь? Что именно должно поддерживаться для работы модуля? Писала хостеру, они ответили, что создали тестовый скрипт и пробовали отправлять тестовое письмо и все работает http://scr.pics/mk8lmt9x79.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы разобраться в причине, надо отлаживать Ваш код по пунктам. И смотреть глубже, а именно:
 1. Параметры отправляемого письма.
 2. Заглянуть внутрь функции $m->Send();

А если не хочется заморачиваться с этими вещими, то просто заюзайте php-функцию:

```
mail($call_email, $subject, $body);
```

Если Вам необходимо установить специфичные параметры письма, то можете их сформировать и передать в эту функцию четвертым параметром.
Подробнее об этой функции можете почитать [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php).

**UPD**
Я так понимаю, вы используете joomla framework, в котором есть встроенная функция отправки почтовых сообщений. Подключается в строке: `JMail::getInstance();`
С joomla я не работал и сказать причину, по которой не отправляется почта, не могу. 
Но есть некоторые предположения:

1. Ошибка в header или parametre
       сформированного письма.
2. Ошибка в кодировке.

Я бы посоветовал вместо строки `$result = $m->Send();` написать `mail($call_email, $subject, $body);` и проверить работоспособность отправки почты. И результат проверки написать сюда. А дальше будем смотреть...

Comment: Спасибо! Этот часто используемый модуль создан http://www.akernel.ru/, не думаю, что там должны быть ошибки, поробую разобраться.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, в скрипте есть ошибки? Раньше ведь все работало.